# Injecting javascript function in nightmareJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

I was given a javascript function that I need to inject into a page in order to get a list of values that would be used later on. I can call this function directly on the webpage using the Chrome console but I want to replicate what I did in the Chrome console in nightmareJS on the webpage that is currently loaded.

This is the function:

```
 function getList() {
  require(['Service/List'], 
  function (Service) 
  { 
    Service.getList
    ({ 
      onComplete: function (listOfServices) 
      { 
        console.log('List:success:' + JSON.stringify(listOfServices)); 

      }, 
      onFailure: function (error) 
      { 
        console.log('List:error:' + error);
      }
    });
  });
} 

getList();
```

I've tried injecting the file but I have had no success, I've also tried adding additional code to that function to write the output to a file but I do not think its being called at all.

Here is the nightmareJS

```
  describe('Open login page', () => {
it('Login', done => {
  nightmare
  .goto('http://loginURL.com')
  .wait('input[type="text"]')
  .wait('input[type="password"]')
  .insert('input[type="text"]', 'username') 
  .insert('input[type="password"]', 'password') 
  .click('input[type="submit"]')
  .evaluate(function() {
    nightmare.inject('js', 'getList.js' )
  })
  //.inject('js', 'getList.js' )
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Done');
  })
})
```

})
})

This is the sample output after injecting the javascript file into the page:

```
List:success:"Test":"https://someURL.com/resource/test","Design":"https://someURL.com/resource/Design"},"NewSpace":"https://someURL.com/resource/NewSpace","Generator":"https://Generator.someURL.com/resource/test","SomethingElse":"https://someURL.com/SomethingElse/test","Connection":"https://someURL.com/Connection/test","WorldWide":"https://someURL.com/resource/WorldWide","Vibes":"https://Vibes.someURL.com/resource/test","GoogleSearch":"https://someURL.com/resource/GoogleSearch",
```

I want to be able to get that output from calling the javascript file on the page and save it to a file so that I can use it later to call other services in that list.

Comment: I think inject has separate scope than scripts on webpage. As a workaround , you might want to inject scripts manually(into <head> element. Have sample code if this approach works for you.

Comment: I think that may work but i'm open to trying anything at this point. If I could see some sample code that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the local javascript files that needs to be injected:

```
var fileData = [];
fileData.push(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('../getList.js'), 'utf-8'));
```

It can be loaded into head section of the page via code:

```
browser.win
    .evaluate(function(fileData) {
      var elem = null;
      for(var ii=0;ii<fileData.length; ii++ ) {
        elem = document.createElement('script');
        if (elem) {
          elem.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); //elem.src = localjs;
          //console.log(fileData[ii]);
          elem.innerHTML = fileData[ii];
          document.head.appendChild(elem);
        }
      }

      console.log("Testing loaded scripts");
      console.log(getList());
      return "Injected Scripts";
    }, fileData)
    .then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Load Error: ", error);
    });
```